# How can I replace every alphabetical lower case letter in a string with its opposite alphabetical lower case letter in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to find the opposite letter using for loop. Also, I would like to note that I am trying to find the opposite letter. For example, replacing "a" with "z", "b" with "y"...

For example, the user inputs this: "3 feg", and the output from this program will be: "uvt". Also, my constraint is 1<=n<=100. The input format is "n input_string_of_length_n", and the output format is "encrypted_string_of_length_n". As a new beginner to programming, I am lost and I do not know how to solve this. Any help will be very much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        `int` user_input_number;
        string user_input_text;
    
        cout << "Type: ";
        cin >> user_input_number;
    
        cout << "Type: ";
        cin >> user_input_text;
    
        for(char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        {
         cout <<  << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Tip: A look-up table, which is just a character array, or in other words...a string.

Comment: what is the output for input `xyz`?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: So what do you do with characters that aren't lowercase alphabetic?  Are they untouched or do you discard them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your own attempt and a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: All letters are lowercase.

Comment: If the input is "feg" how can the output be "uvq"?   "feg" are three consecutive letters but q isn't consecutive with u and v so that doesn't make sense?  Shouldn't the output be "uvt"?

Comment: Sorry it should have been "uvt". "uvq" was a typo.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need a for loop within another for loop.

Comment: @coderlearning3254 You have shown what you have tried. Have you indicated where you are stuck?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/S1SQsUdrv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using ASCII arithmetic:

```
    string s = "abc";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        s[i] = 219 - s[i];
    }
    cout << s; // "zyx"
```

The reason it works is that all [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters are between 0 and 127, and this way the values loop back around

Comment: @PeteBecker, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

string encrypt(int n, string s) {
    map<char, int> alphabetMap = { };
    string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        
        alphabetMap.insert({alpha[i],i});
        
    }
    string coded = "";
    for (int i  = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int index = alphabetMap[s[i]];
        coded += alpha[25 - index];
    }
    
    
    return coded;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    string s = "";
    cout << "Enter n and string: " ;
    cin >> n >> s;
    
    cout << encrypt(n,s) << endl;
    
    
}
```